# How to create child object from existing parent object

Tags: php, oop

I have following **php** class

```
class User implements IUser
{
    public function __construct($i_objParent = NULL)
    {

    }
}
```

When I login successfully I create object of User class.

There is another class named Student class as follows which extends User Class

```
class Student extends User
{
    public function __construct($i_objParent = NULL)
    {
        parent::construct($i_objParent);
    }
}
```

Now as I said eariler I already have object of `User class` how can I construct `Student object` from existing `User Class`.

I think it may be possible by passing existing `User class` object to constructor of child class here `Student class` object?

Also, Is above approach OK?

Comment: write your corresponding constructor which expects a user object and copy its values

Comment: @Fender - I am upto this stage but I am confused how to proceed?

Comment: i am not sure if you can do it automatically. maybe you should assign the value of the fields from `$i_objParent` to the local ones: `$this->myField = $i_objParent->myField;` but i hope that there is a better way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you cannot cast objects in php ( well there are really ugly hacks that work, but i would avoid them ).

Instead there are two ways:

- create a factory class which takes the `User` instance in returns you new `Student` instance with all the data transfered
- use Decorator pattern , which would call methods on `User` instance

Actually there is third way ( one that i would use ) : do not do this.
PHP is not the language for DCI development paradigm. IMHO this whole construction makes no sense. `User` and `Student` are not interchangeable.

Comment: maybe this explains : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505641/the-decorator-design-pattern/505658#505658

Answer (score 0):

One class extending another does not have anything to do with parent / child relationship between them. It's a architecture solution, that allows you to re-use functionality, save on duplicating the code. I am not aware of any automatic call that would get the object that extends User class. I would create a function

```
public function getChild($type)
{
    switch($type)
    {
         case "user":
         return new Student();
         break;
         case "teacher":
         return new Teacher();
         break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to have all classes either abstract or leaf, to avoid such problems. Inheritance cannot be applied to this design, You should change it to either

1 - Using User as a property of Student not as it's parent (which may end up in using Decorator pattern)
2 - Defining User as an abstract class and creating a Student object from the beginning

As you know polymorphic works upside down, and even object casting would not help you in this case.

[Here is the same problem on java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638171/java-creating-a-subclass-object-from-a-parent-object)